# WAMP x64 ext path error

Tags: mysqli, environment-variables, wamp

I'm running WAMP 3.0.6 x64 for Windows 10. PHP v 7 is working fine, but from time to time I need to switch back to PHP v 5.6 to test some legacy projects. When I change version via the WAMP icon mysqli stops working. The module is enabled and exists, but the php error log reveals that the wrong ext path is being used:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/ext/php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

So WAMP is using the PHP v7 ext directory. I thought this might be related to Winodws ENV variables so I set the following for PATH:

C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25

Also my wampmanager.conf file has he following set:

```
phpVersion = "5.6.25"

phpIniDir = "."

phpConfFile = "php.ini"

phpExeDir = "."
```

I've run out of ideas - anyone able to help?

Comment: Have you messed with the `php.ini` file or `phpForApache.ini` file in the PHPV5.6 folder? specifically the `extension_dir` parameter

Comment: **NEVER EVER** add any PHP folder to the Windows PATH in WAMPServer. It will destroy your abililty to make use of the PHP Version switching you say you need to make use of

Comment: Nothing in WAMPServer need to be added to the WINDOW PATH.

Comment: You might also consider upgrading to WAMPServer 3.0.8. This upgrade will NOT change anything to do with Apache, MySQL or PHP. It will just upgrade the WAMPServer internal code to fix/improve some functionality

Comment: @RiggsFolly I removed the windows path vars and found that the phpForApache.ini in the php v5.6 folder were pointing to php v7 ext folder! Not sure how that happened. Edited and now working thank you!